# IIS 7 Permissions

Tags: iis, tfs

I have this peace of code inside an aspx Web Site:

```
var tfs = new TeamFoundationServer(tfsurl
                              , new tworkCredential("", "")
                              , new UICredentialsProvider());
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

When I run it on local machine through Visual Studio I get a windows Log in form. But when i upload the site on the server the forms doesn't come up.I was told that there are some permission for this but i can not find them.

I am using IIS 7 and Windows Server 2008

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of manually putting in the credentials via a UI, have you tried removing the last two parameters of the constructor for the `TeamFoundationServer` object and running the application pool for the web site in IIS under an account that has permissions for TFS?

Comment: I put them there on purpose, so i can get the Log in Window.

Comment: This is running under the context of the IIS server. Are you trying to prompt a user connecting to your custom web site to authenticate with TFS?

Comment: Yes this is what i want to do.

Comment: I would suggest doing this with windows authentication in the IIS configuration. The code above works when running locally because it is running under the context of your account, whereas when it is deployed it is running under the context of whichever account is running that website.

Comment: I don't think that this is an option. You see this code is invoked by a button so the user can validate that his is part of a specific group of TFS. Of course there is a chance that I am wrong. It's the first time i try to work with TFS from a custom web page and I am a bit confused.